# Minimax Lower Bound on Mean Squared Error for average treatment effect in a Bernoulli randomized design?

Tags: standard-error, estimators, treatment-effect, minimax

Does anyone know of any references that show a proof of Minimax Lower Bound on Mean Squared Error for the average treatment effect in a Bernoulli randomized design?

Take a population of $n$ units for which we apply a treatment $Z$ drawn from a Bernoulli distribution, independently for each unit ($Z_i \sim Ber(p)$). Then, for the average treatment effect defined as $ATE = \mathbb{E}[Y(1) - Y(0)]$, I would like to show that

$$\inf\limits_{\widehat{ATE}} \sup\limits_{M \in \mathcal{M}} \mathbb{E}_M[(\widehat{ATE} - ATE(M))^2] = \Omega(1/n),$$

where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the set of viable instances. I'm trying to use LeCam's method (see [Chapter 7 in John Duchi's notes](https://anilkeshwani.github.io/files/John-Duchi-Statistics-311-Electrical-Engineering-377.pdf)), but am not seeing how to show this, even for a linear potential outcomes model. I'm trying to show a much simpler result than in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.05553.pdf) (Theorem 2), but where there is no interference between subjects.

I appreciate any leads or references on this!